# How to fetch the correct url with Aurelia + .Net Core + IIS web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, aurelia

I have an Aurelia app running under Asp MVC Core 1.0.  The app uses HttpClient to call controller actions, which return json data.  The Home controller contains all the actions, and I configure the HttpClient like so:

```
http.configure(config => {
        config
          .useStandardConfiguration()
          .withBaseUrl('Home/');
});
```

When running the application in Visual Studio, everything works.  It's hosted on `localhost:55475`, and when I call `this.http.fetch('GetData')`, it makes a request to `localhost:55475/Home/GetData`.

The problem comes when I deploy to IIS.  The application is deployed as a web application under the default web site, so the root url is `server.org/MyApp`.  The application starts up fine, but when I make the call `this.http.fetch('GetData')`, it requests from `server.org/Home/GetData` instead of `server.org/MyApp/Home/GetData`, which obviously results in a 404.

Why is my fetch request ignoring `MyApp`?  I thought not having a leading slash on my `.withBaseUrl` would make the url relative, but apparently not?

Comment: Just nudging this as I get the same issue. I'm currently investigating how I might pass System.baseURL into the module so that I can pre-pend it for the call to withBaseUrl. However, I just don't get why the App is not using the directory it was loaded from as the base from which to work.

Comment: That's essentially what I did.  I put `@Html.Hidden("rootUrl", Url.Content("~"))` in my view.  I then loaded that value into a a shared module : `this.rootUrl = $('#rootUrl').val();`.  Then I appended `rootUrl` to all my api calls.  Not terribly elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was down to the URL I put into the browser address bar... in your case, does it start to work if you browse to server.org/MyApp/ rather than to server.org/MyApp (note the extra slash)? That worked for me.

So the overall fix I needed to put in place was to have a `base` element at the top of the page hosting Aurelia that set the base URL with a trailing slash e.g.

`<base href="/MyApp/" />`

Which I added using ASP.Net Core with this line in my index.cshtml file:

`<base href="@this.Url.Content("~")/" />`

That or you could redirect your users to the full URL using a 302 response.